# Looking to write vba code to combine data from two Excel worksheets into one

Tags: excel, vba

I understand that the question is pretty broad, but I'd appreciate any help you can give.

The task at hand is to take data from a very messy worksheet (called "Monkey") and sort it into another worksheet (called "Master"). There is one column called "name" which is the only constant between both spreadsheets. I want to write a macro that will take the first row of the "constant" column, find that same row in the constant column of Monkey, and then begin copy-pasting the relevant information.

What I have so far is:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    i = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    While i <= 133
        Set Rng = Range("E" & i)
        If Rng = Worksheets("Monkey").Rng(, -16) Then
            Range("E138").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Success!"
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

--

This is just to test the part of the vba code that will match (printing 'success' if the match is found') The actual copy-pasting subs I'll write myself, but for now, can anyone help with this loop? The constant column is E on master, and U on Monkey. Would setting E2 as a range work, allowing the 2 to increase each time the right row isn't found?

I'm willing to do a lot of experimenting myself, so even the tiniest pieces of advice will help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like that:

- Define the constant name range of Master and Monkey
- For each value of Master, search the monkey equivalent
- If monkey equivalent is found, do what you want

  ```
  Public Sub Test()
      Dim cellMaster As Range, cellMonkey As Range
      Dim rngMasterCst As Range, rngMonkeyCst As Range

      ' Set constants columns from master and monkey
      Set rngMasterCst = Worksheets("master").Range("A1:A500")
      Set rngMonkeyCst = Worksheets("monkey").Range("A1:A500")

      ' For each constant of master
      For Each cellMaster In rngMasterCst
          ' Search for the value in Monkey
          Set cellMonkey = rngMonkeyCst.Find(cellMaster, LookIn:=xlValues)

          ' if the value is find
          If Not cellMonkey Is Nothing Then
              ' Here cellMaster and cellMonkey have the same "constant name"
              ' Navigate in the row with the help of .Offset()
          End If
      Next
  End Sub
  ```

Improvements:

- Use .end(xlDown) on range to find the last row instead of set it static

Comment: Thanks! I found another work-around, but this information is very helpful. Cheers!